# Picture styling in WKInterfacePicker List

Tags: ios, swift, image, watchkit, watchos-2

I made a WKInterfacePicker List. My items are pictures and they are really small.
I didn't find possibility to change size of these pictures in the documentation.

Do you know if it's possible and how can I change it if it's possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't change size of pictures in List. We have to use a Stack.